# Sql query with function that return 2 values

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

How would I return multiple values (say, a number and a string) from a user-defined function in SQL Server inside a query?

e.g `select col1, dbo.function1(col2) from table`

and the result to be

```
Col1 |        Col2       |         Col3
-----+-------------------+---------------------
x    | Num from function | String from function
```

I don't want to call the function 2 times because i use some complex code and i don't want to execute it twice. Just to take the final 2 results in the Return

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Extract from - http://www.sqlteam.com/article/returning-complex-data-from-user-defined-functions-with-cross-apply

> Returning multiple values from a UDF can be done fairly easily in SQL
>   Server, but we must return those values as a virtual table

```
--Sample Table
CREATE TABLE emails 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    EmailAddress VARCHAR(100)
)
GO

--Dummy Data
INSERT INTO emails
SELECT 1,'jeff@jeff.com' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'yak@sqlteam.com' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'billg@microsoft.com'

--UDF Creation
CREATE FUNCTION EmailParse (@email VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS @t TABLE (UserName VARCHAR(20), Domain VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT

    SELECT @i = charindex('@', @email,1);

    IF (@i > 1)
        INSERT INTO @t VALUES (LEFT(@email,@i-1), SUBSTRING(@email,@i+1,20))
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO @t VALUES (NULL,NULL)

    RETURN 
END


--UDF Usage
SELECT 
    emails.ID, s.Username, s.Domain
FROM 
    emails
CROSS APPLY 
EmailParse(emails.EmailAddress) s
```

Answer (score 5):

I would probably create a table UDF.  Something along the lines of this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [owner].[function_name]
(
      @parm1 <datatpe> = <default>
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
      RETURN
      (
      SELECT <column1, column2, ...>
      FROM <table, view, etc.>
      WHERE <some condition applies>      -- optional clauses
)
```

more info [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/building-and-using-table-udfs-in-sql-server/6100403).

It might seem like kind of a waste if you are only returning one row, but I think your alternatives(xml, parsing values from string on the fly) would make things much harder .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about if i want to return 2 declared variables?

Comment: @John Is there something wrong with `RETURN (SELECT @Var1, @Var2)`?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** create a function that returns two values. What's the problem when you call the function twice?

i have found an article in TechNet which explains how to create a [Table-Valued User-Defined Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx).